# Activity cannot receive intent using intent filter and self defined broadcast receiver even the self defined action matches

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

In a class I want to send an intent to my Activity:

```
Intent broadcast = new Intent();
broadcast.setAction("coinchutc.ANNONCE");
Log.d("JoueurAgent", "Sending broadcast " + broadcast.getAction());
context.sendBroadcast(broadcast);
```

The Log can print out message correctly.

In my Activity class I declared a self-defined broadcast receiver:

```
myReceiver = new MyReceiver();
```

The class MyReceiver is like this:

```
private class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("PartieActivity", "receive");
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("coinchutc.ANNONCE")) {
            Log.d("PartieActivity", "Receive " + action);
            annoncer();
        }
    }
}
```

I've registered my activity like this in the onCreate() method of the class:

```
IntentFilter annonceFilter = new IntentFilter();
annonceFilter.addAction("coinchutc.ANNONCE");
registerReceiver(myReceiver, annonceFilter);
```

But the Log in the MyReceiver class doesn't print anything at all.

Does anyone know any other possible reason why it is like this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Have you this in you Manifest?

```
    <receiver android:name="xxx.MyReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="coinchutc.ANNONCE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered such a problem. And I tried to change the action name, then the receiver can receive the intent. I don't know why, but you can have a try.